# How to get the current time in Y-m-d H:i:s.Millisecond format in PHP

Tags: php

if I use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')` the output will be some thing like **2015-11-03 13:25:25.253000**. But i need  **2015-11-03 13:25:25.253** how I can do it?

Comment: [So you can't find a PHP function that will cut the last three characters from a string?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: You don't get `2015-11-03 13:25:25.253000`. You get `2015-11-03 13:25:25.000000`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s'.substr((string)microtime(), 1, 4))`

or what Daniel suggests in the comment down below.

Comment: Just for good style: you shouldn't include variable content in the format string. use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s').substr((string)microtime(), 1, 4)` instead - maybe there is once an optimizer which compiles/caches the format in advance. this will fail with variable strings

Comment: Also, Daniel's method is way faster.